I have a question about INISTATE Code (Analyzing a curved plate)
I'm studying welding-induced residual stresses for curved steel plates.
So, I need to use the INISTATE code taking initial stresses.
This is the picture that I want to analyze.

I divided a curved plate into 4 for taking different initial stresses.

And, I used function-based inistate codes.
(Mat 2&3)'s stress function : y=0.533x - 128.524 & y=-0.533x - 128.524
[These are symmetric about x=0]
So, I wrote the inistate code like that.
(INISTATE code is based on element coordinate system. In the element coordinate system, the x-axis and y-axis directions are swapped. As a result, the residual stress component in the y-axis direction[global reference] was inputted in the x-axis direction[element coordinate system].)

[This is my question point]
What I'm curious about here is that when I look at the stress distribution in the y-axis direction at the first timestep in the analysis results, it's not showing a symmetrical residual stress distribution. I'm wondering what the issue might be.


If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question - but please don't just vandalise the question.
